# How to answer when someone ask to choose a day?

Tags: questions, conversation

Example:

question: Can you send me options [......]?

Should I answer:

Date [xx] - Monday or Wednesday at xx works for me. Would that work for you?

Is this a nice way to answer and is it formal?

Comment: It's fine. Normal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are 'meeting' someone...

> "I am available to meet Monday at 9:00 am or on Thursday at 2:30 pm.  Please let me know if either of those times <strike>are</strike> is acceptable."

Assuming that you have an appointment....

> "I can be there [at the appointment] Monday at 9:00" etc. etc.